# How to use the usage method of $rootScope.Scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how I can use the usage method provided here in the $rootScope.Scope type of AngularJS API Reference. [$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

```
$rootScope.Scope([providers], [instanceCache]);
```

I have tried

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($rootScope) {
var scope = $rootScope.Scope();
```

but i get the error

```
VM3405 angular.min.js:108 TypeError: $rootScope.Scope is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

$rootScope is nothing but your scope object but accessed uniquely in all over app. if you see id of $rootScope it will be 1 always. Here is some code I found we can use for calling method from different files or controllers.

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

    $scope.parentmethod = function() {
        // task
    }
  }
  ]);
 app.controller('two', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
   function($scope) {
     $scope.childmethod = function() {
        $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
    }
  } 
 ]);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I wanted to know how to create a new scope using the instanceCache and providers. If you look under the Usage section in the link given in my question, they have the syntax for the usage and the parameters available. I just do not know where to use this in the code. In the controller or service etc?